# Numpy array construction using tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, list-comprehension

```
C = numpy.array([a^b for a,b in A,B])
```

Is what I attempted. I thought it would xor each individual element in `A` and `B` which are matrices of their own and store it as the same shape within `C`. How would you do this and where is the flaw in my logic?

EDIT: All values within A and B are ints, an example would be both being shape (3,4) containing a range of integers from 0-10

Direct xor

```
C = A^B
```

Resulted in this error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and
>   the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types
>   according to the casting rule 'safe'

The TypeError is confusing me as both A and B contain only ints. A I am 100% certain is all ints. B was constructed the following way:

```
B = np.vstack((A[1:],np.ones(A.shape[1])))
```

Should this not be all ints as well?

Comment: How is the title related to the question?

Comment: Which values are stored in `A` and `B`? Give some examples.

Comment: @lazy1 hahah sorry as terribly phrased as it is it was my best attempt. How would you phrase it? My focus is just on being able to access the individual elements in each in a "pythonic" way to construct the array

Comment: Post an example for A.

Comment: @JohnSmith No you didn't. You have posted an example for B, not for A.

Comment: @miindlek "All values within A and B are ints, an example would be both being shape (3,4) containing a range of integers from 0-10" lol

Comment: @JohnSmith No you are wrong. B has only double values. This is why I asked for it. Look at my answer. I solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your problem is, that `np.ones()` returns an array containing double values. You can't xor double values with the xor operator from numpy. To solve it, you should use the `dtype` parameter when creating B, like this example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,10]])
B = np.vstack((A[1:], np.ones(A.shape[1], dtype=np.int))) # Change this line.

C = A ^ B
```

Output:

```
array([[ 5,  7,  5,  3],
       [ 3, 13, 15, 13],
       [ 6,  9,  8, 11]])
```

Comment: I am still receiving the TypeError :s

Comment: I'll need a more detailed error and probably example of input.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` operator is defined on numpy arrays, if `A` and `B` are tuples then:

```
C = np.array(A) ^ np.array(B)
```

The xor is done in numpy level and should be super fast.

Comment: Sorry A and B are numpy arrays however I am receiving a TypeError still

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to make your current approach work:

```
C = numpy.array([a ^ b for a, b in zip(A, B)])
```

but note that there's a much simpler way:

```
C = A ^ B
```

Demo:

```
>>> A = np.array((1, 2, 3, 4))
>>> B = np.array((2, 3, 1, 4))
>>> A ^ B
array([3, 1, 2, 0])
```

Comment: I am still receiving a TypeError, if you could look at the edit on my original post I would really appreciate it

Comment: @JohnSmith instead of bits and pieces of information, please provide a complete, [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're running along with full error traceback, so that others can replicate the issues you're seeing.